# Elastic Search shows "Unknown key for a START_OBJECT" exception

Tags: elasticsearch

I am sending the following query to elastic search in order to get data which are within the range of the values between the `from` and `to`:

```
{
  "range" : {
    "variables.value.long" : {
      "from" : -1.0E19,
      "to" : 9.1E18,
      "include_lower" : true,
      "include_upper" : true,
      "boost" : 1.0
    }.
  }
}
```

Despite that elastic search throws the following error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "parsing_exception",
                "reason": "Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [range].",
                "line": 2,
                "col": 13
            }
        ],
        "type": "parsing_exception",
        "reason": "Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [range].",
        "line": 2,
        "col": 13
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

Does anybody know what this error means and why I am getting it?

Answer (score 1):

There is some lack of context here like your mappings or the full query you are running, but this is how a range query should look for your document.

**Create index**

```
PUT test_andromachiii
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "variables": {
        "properties": {
          "values": {
            "properties": {
              "long": {
                "type": "double"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index document**

```
POST test_andromachiii/_doc
{
  "variables": {
    "values": {
      "long": 9.1E18
    }
  }
}
```

**Run Query**

```
POST test_andromachiii/_search
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "variables.values.long": {
        "lte": -1.0E19,
        "gte": 9.1E18,
        "boost": 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note lte means lower or equals to, gte greater or equals to.

**Response**

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "test_andromachiii",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "gtGj73cBbr4pOF0Is9my",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "variables" : {
            "values" : {
              "long" : 9.1E18
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using [version `<0.90.4`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/0.90/query-dsl-range-query.html). If that's the case, simply wrap your `range` in a parent `query` object:

```
{
  "query":{
    "range":{
      "variables.value.long":{
        "from":-1.0E19,
        "to":9.1E18,
        "include_lower":true,
        "include_upper":true,
        "boost":1.0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you're using any newer version than that, note that:

> The `from`, `to`, `include_lower` and `include_upper` parameters have been deprecated in 0.90.4 in favour of `gt`, `gte`, `lt`, and `lte`.

Answer (score 0):

This error is saying (somewhat cryptically) that you have a key `range` with an Object value, in a place where that key isn't recognised.

The specific cause here is that your `range` needs to be part of a higher query key such as (i.e.) the [`bool` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/query-dsl-bool-query.html), not part of the main.

Credit: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/unknown-key-for-a-start-object-in-should/140008/3